# Reference ".NET MAUI App" to ".NET MAUI Class Library"

Tags: c#, project, .net-6.0, maui

For my project I need to be able to download the widgets (the View is a DataTemplate in xaml + ViewModel in .cs) from a server and load it during runtime (I use reflection). I am aware this is quite risky way, but this is the requirement.

I did working proof of concept. And now I am implementing a clean version. The problem is that main application is ".NET MAUI App" and the project that would contains the additional widgets I guess should be ".NET MAUI Class Library". In my opinion there is no sense in doing a second project as an app that just contains few classes and few data templates.

The main application contains many useful classes. So I need to project reference it to the additional "widgets" project. But I got an error:

```
Error   NU1201  Project XYZ is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Project XYZ supports:
  - net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
  - net6.0-ios15.4 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
  - net6.0-maccatalyst15.4 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
  - net6.0-windows10.0.19041 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
```

Of course I can do a third... library project that would be referenced to main and the one with widgets... But in real the situation is even more complex and I would like to omit further complications...

**Is there any way to reference ".NET MAUI App" that is all net6.0-..., to a project that is ".NET MAUI Class Library", so the only net6.0 ?**

Comment: What platform do you intend to run this on?

Comment: Windows for the first shot, but later on all of main 4 OS (Windows, macOS, Android and iOS). That is why we have choosen MAUI.NET and so far I have to say I am quite satisfied :) however maybe is too early to say the opinion.

Comment: this will never work on iOS.  It might conceivably work on Widows or Android, I can't say for sure

Comment: Thank you fo rinformation. May you say the reason why this would not go on iOS then? And do you mean the architecture of downloading the xaml and viewmodel and load it via reflection at runtime or do you mean about just referencing the MAUI App in MAUI Class Library. Btw: Really thank you for your contribution!

Comment: iOS does not allow you to modify code at runtime by dynamic compilation and the app bundle is signed so you cannot add libraries to it at runtime

Comment: Thank, I did not know about it. However let me explain. What I really do is compile main application. Give it to users. Then if there is a need for addition of some view. I do in a seperate assembly. Compile it and put a dll on a remote server. When the app launch it always download the dll and perhaps manifest with class names etc. And then at runtime I just create instances of classes from a downloaded assembly. I do not inject an assembly directly. What do you think about it? Surely complicated, but satisfying my client. Anyway would this way be permitted as well on iOS?

Comment: No, this will not work on iOS

Comment: Ok, thank you in advance. That is the pitty. But anyway. Meanwhile I am trying to go with a CommonUtilities project that is going to be referenced. Encountering some further bugs... I am thankful for your support! Have a nice day!